# Overlaying array of strings over char array

Tags: c

I am working a function that needs to be re-entrant - the function is given a memory buffer as an argument and should use such buffer for all its memory needs. In other words, it can't use malloc, but rather should draw the memory the supplied buffer.

The challenge that I ran into is how to overlay an array of strings over a char array of given size (the buffer is supplied as char *), but my result is array of strings (char **).

Below is a repro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 100
#define INPUT_ARRAY_SIZE 3

char *members[] = {
        "alex",
        "danny",
        "max"
};


int main() {
    // this simulates a buffer that is presented to my func
    char *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    char *orig = buffer;
    memset(buffer, NULL, BUFFER_SIZE);

    // pointers will be stored at the beginning of the buffer
    char **pointers = &buffer;

    // strings will be stored after the pointers
    char *strings = buffer + (sizeof(char *) * INPUT_ARRAY_SIZE);

    for(int i = 0; i < INPUT_ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        strncpy(strings, members[i], (strlen(members[i]) + 1));
        // Need to store pointer to string in the pointers section
        // pointers[i] = strings; // This does not do what I expect
        strings += ((strlen(members[i]) + 1));
    }

    for (int i=0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%c", orig[i]);
    }

    // Need to return pointers
}
```

With the problematic line commented out, the code above prints:

```
                alex danny max
```

However, I need some assistance in figuring out how to write addresses of the strings at the beginning.
Of course, if there an easier way of accomplishing this task, please, let me know.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but `NULL` is a null *pointer*, not a "null value". If you want to use `memset` to set memory to zero, then use integer zero `0`.

Comment: As for your problem, remember that arrays naturally decay to pointers to their first element. That makes your array `members` decay to `&members[0]` which is of type `char **`.  So if you want to use your memory as an array of pointers, you should use a variable of type `char **`, like your `pointers` variable but initialized to point to the first byte of `buffer` (instead of the address of the variable `buffer`). Then you can use `pointers` like an array of pointers and initilize its members to point to the strings you copy into the buffer.

Comment: On another unrelated note, why use `strncpy` if you're going to copy the full string and the terminator anyway? Why not use plain `strcpy` instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Damn, got code improvements for days! Seriously, amazing commentary, thank you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Actually `NULL` is a macro with a _null pointer constant_. A _null pointer_ is any pointer wich has a _null pointer value_.

Comment: I agree, in my example, it did not make any sense to use strncpy. In the real function, I do use stncpy where n is set to MAX_MEMBER_LEN - I believe this is more secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here take a look at this.

```
/* conditions : 
 * 
 * 'buffer' should be large enough, 'arr_length','arr' should be valid.
 *            
 */

char ** pack_strings(char *buffer, char * arr[], int arr_length)
{

    char **ptr = (char**) buffer;
    char *string;
    int index = 0;

    string = buffer + (sizeof(char *) * (arr_length+1));  /* +1 for NULL */
    while(index < arr_length)
    {
        size_t offset;

        ptr[index] = string;
        offset = strlen(arr[index])+1;
        strcpy(string,arr[index]);

        string += offset;
        ++index;
    }
    ptr[index] = NULL;
    return ptr;
}
```

usage

```
   char **ptr = pack_strings(buffer,members,INPUT_ARRAY_SIZE);

   for (int i=0; ptr[i] != NULL; i++)
       puts(ptr[i]);
```

Comment: Thank you Binary_10 - Exactly what I was looking for.